# Zend DB get Distinct count

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

hi i have the following result from query:

```
    public function getCityCategory($city_id)
        {
            $select = $this->getDbTable()->getAdapter()->select();
            $select->from('business as b', array('b.cat_id'))
                 ->joinInner('business_category as bc','b.cat_id = bc.cat_id',array('bc.cat_name'))
                 ->where('b.city_id='.$city_id);
$result = $this->getDbTable()->getAdapter()->fetchAll($select);
            return $result;    
        }




Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cat_id] => 1
            [cat_name] => Restaurants
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cat_id] => 1
            [cat_name] => Restaurants
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [cat_id] => 1
            [cat_name] => Restaurants
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [cat_id] => 5
            [cat_name] => Arts & Entertainment
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [cat_id] => 11
            [cat_name] => Hotels & Travel
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [cat_id] => 7
            [cat_name] => Nightlife
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [cat_id] => 20
            [cat_name] => Financial Services
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [cat_id] => 22
            [cat_name] => Attractions
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [cat_id] => 2
            [cat_name] => Active Life
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [cat_id] => 22
            [cat_name] => Attractions
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [cat_id] => 7
            [cat_name] => Nightlife
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [cat_id] => 1
            [cat_name] => Restaurants
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [cat_id] => 1
            [cat_name] => Restaurants
        )

)
```

The query return all category for specific `city_id` now when i add distinct the above code i get the following result:

```
public function getCityCategory($city_id)
        {

          $select = $this->getDbTable()->getAdapter()->select();
            $select->from('business as b', array('b.cat_id'))
                 ->joinInner('business_category as bc','b.cat_id = bc.cat_id',array('bc.cat_name'))
                 ->distinct()
                 ->where('b.city_id='.$city_id);
   $result = $this->getDbTable()->getAdapter()->fetchAll($select);
            return $result;    
        }

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cat_id] => 1
            [cat_name] => Restaurants
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cat_id] => 5
            [cat_name] => Arts & Entertainment
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [cat_id] => 11
            [cat_name] => Hotels & Travel
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [cat_id] => 7
            [cat_name] => Nightlife
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [cat_id] => 20
            [cat_name] => Financial Services
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [cat_id] => 22
            [cat_name] => Attractions
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [cat_id] => 2
            [cat_name] => Active Life
        )

)
```

Now the question on how can i add count on last query so i can get total num of business for each category since distinct remove duplicate category? So the end result should be like this

```
[0] => Array
            (
                [cat_id] => 1
                [cat_name] => Restaurants
                [count] => 5
            ) ....
```

Thanks

Comment: Find sum first and then remove duplicates

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
 count(cat_name) as count
```

and then

```
group by cat_name
```